# Series expansion for $\text{Li}_2(x)$? Why is this wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4704809/1174256) it is claimed by @ClaudeLeibovici that $\text{Li}_2(x)$ has the following power series expansion:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{2(n+1)}\,x^{2n+1}$$
However, this seems wrong to me, since
$$S(1)\simeq0.5797622205888950\dots$$
$$\text{Li}_2(1)\simeq1.6449340668482\dots$$
and this is just one counterexample, they differ for every value of $x$. To get the series, they suggest to take the series for $-\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}$ and integrate termwise, but the series expansion for this function is
$$-\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}$$
which, when integrated from $0$ to $z$ leads to
$$\text{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k^2}$$ which is just the definition of the dilogarithm! So no digamma functions at all!

Also, if you remove the $2$ in the denominator of the series (it could be a typo), the result is still wrong.

Do you have any clue of what is going on here? Am I missing something? Or is this just wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One view for the series:
$$ S_{2}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{2(n+1)}\,x^{2n+1}. $$
Using an integral definition for $\psi(x)$ then
$$ \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right) - \psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right) = 2 \, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{n+1} \, du}{1+u}. $$
With this the series reduces to
$$ S_{2}(x) = - \frac{1}{x} \, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x^2 \, u) \, du}{1+u}. $$
This can be evaluated further and is
$$ S_{2}(x) = \frac{1}{x} \, \left( \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right) - \ln(1-x^2) \, \ln\left(\frac{2 \, x^2}{1+x^2}\right) \right). $$

An example of the use of this result is:
$$ S_{2}(1) = \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\zeta(2) - \ln^{2}(2)}{2}. $$

Using integration by parts on the integral for $S_{2}(x)$ leads to
\begin{align}
- x \, S_{2}(x) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x^2 \, u) \, du}{1+u} \\
&= \left[ \ln(1+u) \, \ln(1-x^2 \, u) + x^2 \, \int \frac{\ln(1+u) \, du}{1 - x^2 \, u} \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= \left[ \ln(1+u) \, \ln(1-x^2 \, u) - \ln(1+u) \, \ln\left(\frac{1-x^2 \, u}{1+x^2}\right) - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{(1+u) \, x^2}{1+x^2}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= - \left( \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{2 \, x^2}{1+x^2}\right) - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right) - \ln 2 \, \ln(1+x^2) \right)
\end{align}
which gives
$$ S_{2}(x) = \frac{1}{x} \, \left( \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{2 \, x^2}{1+x^2}\right) - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right) - \ln 2 \, \ln(1+x^2) \right). $$
With this form there may be a transformation that can be used that could reduce $S_{2}(x)$ further. It does not appear that it could be reduced to $\text{Li}_{2}(x)$.

Comment: Now it is clear, thank you. It remains to understand how Claude got the correct result I was asking even getting this series wrong.

Comment: @Zima   The person behind the name Claude is skillful enough to know what the process, result, and ideas should be to obtain a result but can also make a typo in some cases. As it is currently the series proposed is interesting enough for further study and may not be in readily found books.

Comment: I know very well how skillful Claude is. And this is precisely why I want to understand what went wrong. This result, maybe without the typo, would be very intriguing if true, and I want to make this possible

Answer (score 1):

"Dilogarithm" has two common meanings.  One is the one you state.  The other is $$
\operatorname{dilog}(x) := \int_1^x\frac{\ln(t)}{1-t}\;dt = \operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)
$$
I guess this is where the hint comes from.

But still: $\operatorname{dilog}(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1.644934068$ and $\operatorname{dilog}(1) = 0$.  So I do not know about Claude's series $S(x)$.